# Legendary Badge awarded at 0:00

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges, timestamps, daily-reputation-badges

I was looking at the list of users who earned the legendary badge. Since October 24, 2014, all users who earned this badged earned it at 0:00. As far as I'm concerned, that time does not exist. Either this is a bug, or the zeroth hour is just a special time when legends choose to reveal themselves.

#### As you can see, all the badges below were awarded at 0:00:

[image]

#### As shown in the image below, the last time the proper time was recorded was on October 24, 2012:

[image]

Comment: IIRC, 0:00 === UTC Midnight. Lots of things happen around UTC Midnight, like calculating newly awarded badges. This does happen regularly throughout the day though. The thing to remember is to [always blame caching](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/), things don't always happen.... RIGHT NOW! Some things happen on a schedule. I could be wrong though, it has happened at least once before.

Comment: @TinyGiant This HASN'T happened regularly throughout the day though since Oct 24, 2012 while before then it did.

Comment: When looking through the other badges, it seems like a lot of them have different update intervals. I'm sure there are many different reasons for each badge's specific interval. For this one, It would make sense that it updates at UTC Midnight, as it requires you to have hit your rep cap at the end of the day. You can hit your rep cap before the end of the day, then lose some rep. If it updated at any time other than UTC Midnight then you may have issues with gaining and subsequently losing badges, which would cause major outcries from the community.

Comment: @TinyGiant So what about all the people who earned it mid-day before Oct 14, 2012? I have yet to hear outcries.

Comment: Why was the mid-day awarding suddenly stopped?

Comment: *As far as I'm concerned, that time does not exist* - It most certainly does, it's midnight.

Comment: How come one user is in the list with 1 rep point?

Comment: @EricMartinez That user is/was suspended when the screenshot was taken.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> As far as I'm concerned, that time does not exist.

I'd like to introduce you to a [24 hour clock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-hour_clock). 0:00 is midnight.

---

For the rest of your question, about why this badge is awarded at midnight instead of through out the day, I imagine it's because the badge is a "daily" badge:

> Earn 200 daily reputation 150 times.

Since reputation can go up and down through out the day, awarding it the instant someone reaches 200 points is rather premature. If someone comes along and down votes you 5 minutes later, you didn't earn 200 points that day. You earned 198.

Additionally, it's a very rare badge. It's only been awarded 14 times in 2015 (as of July 24). There is no need to constantly run the check to see if someone has met the criteria for this badge when it is happening, on average, twice a month. Scheduling such a check makes sense to save resources. Midnight is a fairly normal time to run a scheduled task.

Comment: I've always used 24:00 for midnight. I didn't know 0:00 notation is also used.

Comment: According to this answer, it seems that this "bug" I found is actually a functional improvement made in October 2012. Is that correct?

Comment: @TotZam Honestly... you're mostly just overthinking it. Some badges are awarded on a schedule. *When* that triggers is fairly irrelevant.

Comment: @TotZam there is no 24:00. I think you are mixing it up with the 12-hour clock ("analog clock"), where the lack of hour 0 is just one of many illogical things

Comment: @Krumelur: 24:00 *is* used to indicate "end of day" in certain scenarios - it's even covered in ISO-8601. It's very rarely used in computer-reported times though.

Comment: @JonSkeet You are right, I remember using it like that after a long discussion on how to best let users input "end of day". But used like that, I would say it is more related to time intervals rather than points in time.

Comment: @AnnaLear I just found it strange since it USED to be awarded NOT on a schedule.